# LOAD DATA INFILE not working in mariadb

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mariadb

Iam trying to migrate from mysql to mariadb. On this time I can face an issue with mariadb.

When I can trying to load a data file into a table, it shows an error like :

**SQL Error (29): File 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Local Settings/Temp/SAMPLE/DATA_TEMP1351761841668/SampleFile0' not found (Errcode: 2)**

But the file already exists in the path....

Another one point is that the same command successfully works with MySQL.
Is MariaDB has any permission issue?

*See below my query :*

```
load data infile "'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Local Settings/Temp/SAMPLE/DATA_TEMP1351761841668/SampleFile0" into table SAMPLETABLE;
```

When changing the path like `"C:/SampleFile0",` its working properly. Path from `Administrator` folder it doesn't working.

Can anyone help me in this regard??? Iam a newone in MariaDB.

Comment: Iam login as Administrator. Same command works successfully in MySQL

Comment: is your mysql server running in local?

Comment: Yes, my mysql server and mariadb server are running in local machine on different ports.

Comment: It looks weird, can you try again with double slash? example: "c:/folder" to "c:\\folder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try to add "local" ?

```
load data local infile "'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Local Settings/Temp/SAMPLE/DATA_TEMP1351761841668/SampleFile0" into table SAMPLETABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an unwanted single quote in your command.